# Is there a recommended naming convention for files that contain only functions/extension methods?

Tags: naming, kotlin

In Java, it is simple: file name for a type is the name of a type plus `.java` suffix.

In Kotlin, you can write files that don't contain classes. Is there any convention to name them?

And also how would you name unit test classes for those functions?

Comment: I group them by behavior and name the file accordingly. For example, extension methods for collections go to CollectionUtils.kt

Comment: This is totally subjective.

Comment: @KirillRakhman Grouping functions by behaviour and naming the file accordingly is definitely the way to go, but adding the "Utils" suffix does not really contribute to describing what that behaviour is

Comment: When helping me write an Android app in Kotlin, my fellow iOS developer colleague decided to borrow the funky naming convention for extension files from Swift, so they would call the files like `String+toShortName.kt`. Although it did look very unnatural, I have to admit that all related code was really easy to find and navigate.

Answer (score 28):

`StringExt.kt` for the file with extension functions of `String`.

`CollectionExt.kt` for Collections extension functions.

Answer (score 21):

I like [WangJie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2124006/wangjie)'s suggestion of adding a `Ext` suffix to the filename to communicate that it's a file which contains extensions. (Personally I'd add `Extensions` instead of `Ext` but in principle it's the same as what [WangJie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2124006/wangjie) is suggesting.)

I see by browsing the files in the Kotlin library however that there's a bit of a convention of pluralising the name of the class or type of class for which extensions are being added, e.g. [Arrays.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Arrays.kt), [Collections.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Collections.kt), [Maps.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Maps.kt), [MutableCollections.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/MutableCollections.kt), [Strings.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/text/Strings.kt). The [Source file names](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#source-file-names) section of the [Coding conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html) document also alludes to this.

Answer (score 13):

As for a file with just extension functions, based on the [Source files organization](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#source-file-organization) section in the docs, you should not create files like this:

> Avoid creating files just to hold all extensions of some class.

Instead you should either put the extensions with the class they extend or in the client of them.
I personally think this guideline overlooks a pretty fundamental use case: extension functions for classes not owned by you with multiple clients. Also extension functions that have dependencies on classes you don't want to introduce in the module where the extended class is.

In this case it might be good to give a meaningful name instead of `FooExt.kt` (if all these extension functions have a common purpose). If they don't, it might not make sense to keep them all in the same file. I'm referring to the [Source file names](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#source-file-names) guideline where it states:

> If a file contains multiple classes, or only top-level declarations, choose a name describing what the file contains, and name the file accordingly.

Comment: Yes... "Placing multiple declarations in the same Kotlin source file is encouraged as long as these declarations are closely related to each other semantically" — say the Kotlin coding convention docs. But the problem is, that way, in the project files view in our IDE, we don't get to see the convenient icons that help us differentiate between files with objects, classes, data classes, enum classes, abstract classes, interfaces, etc. any more :(

Answer (score 2):

My approach to this is to put all the extension methods into a package named `extensions` and the methods into files that are named according to the class they extend, like `Int.kt` or `String.kt`.